# Parsing XML with python and ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am do class project where I have to save a list of links to a text file.

I given the XML and am trying to **iterate through all the url's** but am troubles.

I have tried using element tree but can not iterate through the  I read many other questions and tried that with no success. Please help

The structure like this

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.crawlingcourse.com/sitemap/1.3">
  <url>
     <loc>
        http://www.crawlingcourse.com/item-3911512
     </loc>
  </url>
<url>....
```

Comment: What does your code look like so far? In what way is it not working?

Comment: From the example, just want to make sure your XML is correct (all elements closed, doctype, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) to efficiently parse an XML file.

```
from lxml import etree
```

Your XML sample is not well-formed, I fixed it like this:

```
content = """\
<urlset xmlns="http://www.crawlingcourse.com/sitemap/1.3">
  <url>
     <loc>
        http://www.crawlingcourse.com/item-3911512
     </loc>
  </url>
</urlset>"""
```

To parse a file, you can use `etree.parse()`. But since this sample is a string, I use `etree.XML()`:

```
tree = etree.XML(content)
```

The natural way to search elements in a XML tree is using XPath. For instance, you can do that:

```
loc_list = tree.xpath("//url/loc")
```

But You'll get nothing:

```
for loc in loc_list:
    print(loc.text)
# None
```

The reason, an it is probably your problem, is that `<urlset>` use a default namespace: "http://www.crawlingcourse.com/sitemap/1.3".

To make it work, you need to use `xpath()` function with this namespace. Let's give a name to this namespace: "s":

```
NS = {'s': "http://www.crawlingcourse.com/sitemap/1.3"}
```

Then, use the `s` prefix in your XPath expression like this:

```
loc_list = tree.xpath("//s:url/s:loc", namespaces=NS)

for loc in loc_list:
    print(loc.text)
#     http://www.crawlingcourse.com/item-3911512
```

Because your XML is indented, you need to strip the spaces:

```
for loc in loc_list:
    url = loc.text.strip()
    print(url)
# http://www.crawlingcourse.com/item-3911512
```

Comment: Thank you @Laurent for taking the time to explain. You solved my problem and taught me how it actually works. thank u

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue really is the namespace.

Here's working code:

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import XML, fromstring, tostring, ElementTree
xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0"?><urlset><url><loc>http://www.crawlingcourse.com/item-3911512</loc></url></urlset>'
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(xml_string))
print [elem.text for elem in tree.iter(tag='loc')]
```

Now, if you want to add `<urlset xmlns="http://www.crawlingcourse.com/sitemap/1.3">`, the tags are going to be different. From http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp:

> XML Namespaces - The xmlns Attribute. When using prefixes in XML, a
>   namespace for the prefix must be defined. The namespace can be defined
>   by an xmlns attribute in the start tag of an element. The namespace
>   declaration has the following syntax. xmlns:prefix="URI".

Threw me off too!